# Capture window state in a form,

Tags: javascript, forms, input, global-variables, user-defined-functions

I have a form that is used to print the essential contents of a page.  The page has columns that can be show or hidden.  I want to determine which cols are being shown and which are hidden to pass to the print routine.   I am trying to use a form to pass that but can't seem to get it to work.

```
<tr><td align='left' width='100'>
<form action='print_plan.php' method='post'       name='printplan' target='_blank'>
<input type='hidden' id='PlanNo' name='PlanNo' value='13' />
<input type='hidden' id='IDuser' name='IDuser' value='1' />
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
 document.write("<input type='hidden' id='detCols' name='detCols' value='",details,"' />")
</script>
<input name='Submit' type='image' value='print' title='Print Plan'  src='images/print.gif'
           alt='Print Plan' onclick='detailCols()' /></form></td>
```

Where detailCols will generate a global variable "details" with a bit mask of the column sets that are showing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this might be the answer:
try to add your hidden field statically to html, with a null value. then set its value dynamically using jQuery:

```
<td align='left' width='100'>
<form action='print_plan.php' method='post' name='printplan' target='_blank'>
<input type='hidden' id='PlanNo' name='PlanNo' value='13' />
<input type='hidden' id='IDuser' name='IDuser' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' id='detCols' name='detCols' value='' />
<input name='Submit' type='image' value='print' title='Print Plan'  src='images/print.gif'
           alt='Print Plan' onclick='detailCols()' />
</form>
</td>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#detCols").val(details);
});
```